# DataTables pagination style doesn't styled as bootstrap theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatable

I try to use DataTables on my Web. I'm using bootstrap version 3.3.6 from here: http://getbootstrap.com/

I'm using DataTables example from here: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html

This is what I expected:

[image: expected]

But this is what I get:

[image: what I get]

Here is my code:

```
<head>
 <!-- Bootstrap -->
 <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
 <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- Bootstrap theme -->
 <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- Datatable css -->
 <link href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
 <link href="theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <!-- some other stuff and html code here -->

 <!-- and, at the end of page, I have: -->
 <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/docs.min.js"></script> 
 <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
 <script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').DataTable();
      } );
 </script>
</body>
```

Did I missed something? I've tried to compare my code and example code from example here: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html

but still no found any different

edit: I add theme.css to my page, it only like this:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.theme-dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  position: static;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.theme-showcase > p > .btn {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.theme-showcase .navbar .container {
  width: auto;
}
```

Comment: First look at your code makes me think that there must be something in theme.css (must be custom css) that's overriding the datatable's default pagination styles.

Comment: this is theme.css : `body {
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.theme-dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  position: static;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.theme-showcase > p > .btn {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.theme-showcase .navbar .container {
  width: auto;
}`

Comment: Try including only these css files (plus your theme.css). No changes in scripts and html.
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../media/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css">

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try It help you this code work my projects

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.css"/> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jqc-1.11.3,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.js"></script>  


    <div style="clear: both;margin-top: 18px;">
      <table id="example" class="display table table-striped table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>SKILL</th>             
                  <th>EDIT</th>
                  <th>DELETE</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            <tbody>
             <tr>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
             </tr>
              .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
     <tr>
               <td>10</td>
               <td>10</td>
               <td>10</td>
               <td>10</td>
             </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>

      </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
     var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
               "pageLength": 5,
                "pagingType": "full_numbers"
          });
        $('#example').removeClass( 'display' ).addClass('table table-striped table-bordered');
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: hey bayuforest You have to create simple html code then you have migrate your project

Comment: thanks. I've change my source of datatable.min.css and datatable.min.js just like your code, now everything work as I expected. thank again

Answer (score 4):

maybe I'm late, but here is what I've found out having the same problem

**switch order to those scripts**

jquery datatables is supposed to be first, then the bootstrap version, that will fix the button problem, I know it works because when adding dataTables.bootstrap.min.js I accidentally removed jquery.dataTables.min.js
made the mistake of adding it the way you have in your source code and it didn't work until I switched them

Comment: I've tried your solution on my code (in another project). And this is also work for me. Just like you, I accidentally removed it too :) Thanks again.